# windows 8.1 screen brightness

Tags: windows-8.1, display

I have recently installed windows 8.1 and its working fine. but the brightness was not working at all. then i did the following to find a solution..

1. I opened the device manager and click on the display adapter.
2. I click on update driver option.
3. then I  click on  the 2nd  option "brows my computer for driver software"
4. I click on "let me pick from the list of device drivers"
5. I select 'microsoft basic display adapter" ( as it was the only available driver) and click on next...

as it was updated but still the brightness is not working..
any solution please???????

Comment: Why don't you install the vendors display drivers?

Comment: I don't know exactly which drivers should i install????

Comment: What hardware are we talking about? Laptop? Pc ?

Comment: its a "Haier laptop Y11b"

Comment: I am unable to find vendors support for your laptop, but you can try this website download their utility that will automatically scan and download all the needed drivers for you at https://drp.su/drivers/notebooks/?v=Haier&m=Y11B&id=259684&l=en

Comment: i have recently installed all the available drivers from this website... but still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very very hard to find...!!!

here is the link to zip file containing all the drivers for Y11B Tablet from Haier's china web site.

```
http://www.haier.com/bigfiles/directory/cn/Notebook/20150613/bf1207995058.zip
```

Comment: i have downloaded this zip file three times, but every time when i try to open it, this error is displayed " can not open this file try download again...

Comment: Ok, lets try something else. I know that Intel M 5Y10c processor is equipped with Intel HD Graphics 5300. Try downloading this driver from intel website.

Comment: You are welcome :), if I was helpful to you please mark my answer as a solution.